# Type mismatch when setting ADODB Recordset Date field. (VB6)

Tags: date, vb6, recordset, variant

I have had reports of type mismatch errors in our program, and error logging points it to a line of code where we set a date field in a recordset to a date value stored in a variant, seen below:

```
RS![DateField] = mDateVariant
```

Unfortunately, whoever wrote the logging did not think to log the value which was causing the error in the first place, and this issue is apparently not always a frequent one.

The Variant value mDateVariant is either set via a string which itself was assigned its value from another date field in the database, or by using the Date function.

```
mDateVariant = Date
```

OR

```
mstrOtherDate = RS![DifferentDateField]
mDateVariant = mstrOtherDate
```

It may be worth noting that some of our users are international (Canada), though I set my system's Date and Time settings for Canada, and did not see any issues running this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: Always use explicit syntax like `RS![DateField].Value = mDateVariant` to avoid inadvertant side effects from default property action.  You will also run into trouble with string data here, since ADO will do any necessary type coercion using the locale settings in effect when the VB6 runtime initiated OLE services.  To get reliable results from string-sourced datetime values you need to actually parse the string into a Date typed value yourself - and I don't mean just applying `CDate()` to the text either!